# PHP get value from url, in a standalone php file (not index.php)

Tags: php

I got 2 separate PHP files on server. `index.php` and `mailer.php`. they are not connected in any ways. mailer.php is simply there to handle contact from.
Inside my  `index.php` file using `$_GET` variable i store language of webpage in `$lang = $_GET['lang'];` which is visible in a webpage url http://nikolozasatiani.com/version2/index.php?lang=en .

How do I create a variable inside  `mailer.php` to indicate webpage language. p.s it would be nice if u do not use require/include in your solution. it would be better to use url

Comment: Why can't you do the same as index.php?

Comment: you can create a browser cookie based on lang and then use that instead of variable?

Comment: You can store the language in the $_SESSION.

Comment: could u tell me exactly how do i store language in the $_SESSION and how i call this variable in a mailer.php?

Comment: Why don't you [read about sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and see where you have problems?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, make use of [**$_SESSION**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

So typically, you would do something like this:

### index.php

```
session_start(); // put this at the top of the page, preferably first line
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
```

### mailer.php

```
session_start(); // put this at the top of the page, preferably first line
.
.
.
echo $_SESSION['lang'];
```

---

You can also make use of [**$_COOKIE**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

### index.php

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';

 /*
 the cookie will expire in 1 hour
 the fourth parameter ("/") makes this cookie available throughout the application
*/
setcookie("Lang", $lang, time()+3600, "/");
```

### mailer.php

```
echo $_COOKIE['Lang'];
```

Comment: Might be nice to set a default. `$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';` and then run this through language validations

Answer (score 0):

If your application is mission critical, as all decent comm apps are bound to be, the only fireproof way is to store said data serverside.  All local variables / browser data is subject to user interference / disruption.

If you implement user control, and again i cant see a scenario where you wouldnt, that should be quite straightforward to include in mysql db.

Comment: Storing the user preference on application language doesn't require a server-side database. Assuming the language is put through validation, storing the users preference locally for their browsing session is *fine*.

Comment: as long as the application is not MISSION CRITICAL, you are correct.  communications (mailer) tend to be not only missio critical, but also quite secretive.  take as an example a twostep authentication (like google mailer api or even a simpler openid protocol).